# Correct case in namerefs

Tags: hyperref, capitalization

I'd like to use `nameref`s within a sentence, and have the case of the resulting text match the position within the sentence. The section title is naturally title case, but is there some command to either a) force lowercase of `nameref`s (`\lowercase{}` doesn't work), or b) insert init-case, i.e., uppercase the initial word if it's at the beginning of a sentence, lowercase elsewhere?

Example:

```
\section{Object}
\label{sec:obj}
[definition of an object]
...
\nameref{sec:obj} instance variables are often called simply "\nameref{sec:obj}".
```

should produce:

```
Object
[definition of an object]
...
Object instance variables are often called simply "object".
```

Note case difference at the start and in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: An example would be useful here: from the description it is pretty hard to follow what is required.

Comment: I don't think the <a href="http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases">[cases]</a> tag is appropriate for this question; the other two articles with the tag are talking about the `cases` environment from `amsmath`...

Comment: Whoops, apparently that's *not* the way to do a hyperlink in a comment. (Wishes comments were previewable...)

Answer (score 12):

I think that it would be hard for TeX to *automatically* know whether the `\nameref` should be title-case, lowercase, or init-case.  But if *you* are prepared to tell TeX, then this can be done.  I don't claim that this is the most elegant method, but it's the one that I use in a similar situation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\lnameref}[1]{%
\bgroup
\let\nmu\MakeLowercase
\nameref{#1}\egroup}
\newcommand{\fnameref}[1]{%
\bgroup
\def\nmu{\let\nmu\MakeLowercase}%
\nameref{#1}\egroup}


\newcommand{\nmu}{}

\begin{document}

\section{\nmu This \nmu Is a \nmu Section}
\label{sec}

\lnameref{sec} is a section.

\nameref{sec} is a section.

\fnameref{sec} is a section.

\nameref{sec} is a section.

\end{document}
```

Produces:

> 1 This Is a Section
>
> this is a section is a section.
>   This Is a Section is a section.
>   This is a section is a section.
>   This Is a Section is a section.

(It makes a modicum more sense when the "this is a section" looks like a link since then it looks like '"this is a section" is a section'.  Only when I transcribed it did I realise how daft it looked.)

Comment: Thanks! Two questions: what does `nmu` mean and does `\nmu Word` only act on the first character of the following word, *i.e.* `W` in this case?

Comment: @Atcold (Trying to reconstruct 13-year old thinking!).  I don't remember what `nmu` stood for, but its role is as a _hook_ so that code can be inserted to change the case of the following letter.  If it is set to `\MakeLowercase` then because that takes an argument of one token, then it does act on the next letter. In theory, it could absorb multiple characters and do weird things with them, but in this use-case it switches between "do nothing" and "make the next token lower case".

Comment: Yup, yup, makes sense. Thanks! Let me know if you end up figuring out what the macro name meant. :')

Comment: @Atcold This is probably a _backronym_, but my best guess is that it stands for "next maybe uppercase"