# Capitalization variants of nameref

Tags: hyperref, nameref

Several packages that generate inline text (i.e. glossaries, [cleverref](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)) have commands to let the author choose capitalization. In particular, glossaries seems to be able to do parts of this automatically.

However, `nameref` (of the `nameref` package) is unable to change the capitalization of the referenced text. As `nameref` is often used to reference section titles which are capitalized text starts looking wrong, when the capitalization is kept up mid sentence.

While there is [one answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1655/19326) on here that solves this problem, it relies on inserting a macro infront of every letter for which the capitalization should be adjusted.

1. Given that commands for modifying capitalization are available (`\MakeUppercase`, `\MakeLowercase`, [`\makefirstuc`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mfirstuc/mfirstuc-manual.pdf)), why is it so hard to provide `nameref` commands that return the name in all lowercase or all but the first letter lowercase?
2. Would it be possible to protect parts of a heading from capitalization changes? (i.e. `\MakeUppercase{so\MakeLowercase{WhAT}}` returns `SOwhat` (see Texbook page 42 for details))

i.e:

```
\section{This is about \MakeUppercase{PCI}e on Mainboards}

\nameref    -> This is about PCIe on Mainboards    normal
\lcnameref  -> this is about PCIe on mainboards    LowerCase
\ucnameref  -> This Is About PCIe On Mainboards    UpperCase
\fucnameref -> This is about PCIe on mainboards    FirstUpperCase
```

---

I tried extending `nameref` by copying the definition of `\nameref` and wrapping all occurences of `\@thirdoffive{#1}` in `\MakeLowercase` however the result was quite unexpected: for the input `This Is a Section` I got `11This Is a Sectionsection.1`.

I actually had to copy the .sty file, as using `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` in the preamble for the new definition resulted in warnings about undefined macros.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**hyperref/nameref** makes extensive use of the `\AtBeginDocument`-hook.

In case you wish to redefine some internals of the **nameref**-package, you need to use the `\AtBeginDocument`-hook, too.

Otherwise your changes done in the preamble will be overridden when **hyperref/nameref**'s `\AtBeginDocument`-thingies are carried out.

The example below delivers three macros `\fucnameref`, `\ucnameref` and `\lcnameref`.

For case-changing the macros from *Nicola Talbot's* [**mfirstuc**](https://ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc)-package are used.

Thus within the arguments of sectioning-commands you can use the tricks explained in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfirstuc/mfirstuc-manual.pdf) of that package.

I highly recommend reading that [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfirstuc/mfirstuc-manual.pdf) as it also explains the many pitfalls with that package.

With that package you can use a preceding empty group `{}` for preventing evaluation of commands. E.g., you can use `{}\MakeUppercase` and `{}\MakeLowercase` for ensuring uppercased-letters/lowercased-letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}[2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX]
\usepackage{mfirstuc}[2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)]

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand\My@Macro[1]{#1}%
  \newcommand\My@Thirdoffive[5]{\My@Macro{#3}}%
  \renewcommand*\@namerefstar[1]{%
    \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\My@Thirdoffive
  }%
  \renewcommand*\T@nameref[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\label\@gobble
    \NR@setref{#1}\My@Thirdoffive{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\fucnameref{%
    \@ifstar\fucnameref@star\fucnameref@nostar
  }%
  \newcommand\callemakefirstuc[1]{%
    \MakeLowercase{\emakefirstuc{#1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\fucnameref@star[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\My@Macro=\callemakefirstuc
    \nameref*{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \newcommand\fucnameref@nostar[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\My@Macro=\callemakefirstuc
    \nameref{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\ucnameref{%
    \@ifstar\ucnameref@star\ucnameref@nostar
  }%
  \newcommand\ucnameref@star[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \MFUhyphentrue
    \let\My@Macro=\ecapitalisefmtwords
    \nameref*{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \newcommand\ucnameref@nostar[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \MFUhyphentrue
    \let\My@Macro=\ecapitalisefmtwords
    \nameref{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\lcnameref{%
    \@ifstar\lcnameref@star\lcnameref@nostar
  }%
  \newcommand\lcnameref@star[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\My@Macro=\MakeLowercase
    \nameref*{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \newcommand\lcnameref@nostar[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\My@Macro=\MakeLowercase
    \nameref{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\SomeSectionTitle{%
  Some very Nice section Title with 
  {}\texorpdfstring{{}\MakeUppercase{pci}}{PCI} and
  {}\texorpdfstring{{}\MakeLowercase{PCI}}{{}pci}%
}

\begin{document}

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{verbatim}
\newcommand\SomeSectionTitle{%
  Some very Nice section Title with 
  {}\texorpdfstring{{}\MakeUppercase{pci}}{PCI} and
  {}\texorpdfstring{{}\MakeLowercase{PCI}}{{}pci}%
}

\section{\SomeSectionTitle}\label{NiceLabel}
\end{verbatim}

yields:

\section{\SomeSectionTitle}\label{NiceLabel}

\verb|\nameref{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \nameref{NiceLabel}

\verb|\fucnameref{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \fucnameref{NiceLabel}

\verb|\ucnameref{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \ucnameref{NiceLabel}

\verb|\lcnameref{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \lcnameref{NiceLabel}

\verb|\nameref*{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \nameref*{NiceLabel}

\verb|\fucnameref*{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \fucnameref*{NiceLabel}

\verb|\ucnameref*{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \ucnameref*{NiceLabel}

\verb|\lcnameref*{NiceLabel}| yields:\\ \lcnameref*{NiceLabel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit on Friday, September 7, 2018:

Please don't try to nest calls to `\fucnameref` or  to `\ucnameref` or to `\lcnameref`—i.e., don't do try things like

```
\section{Some Nice Section}\label{NiceSection}
...
\section{annotations to \lcnameref*{NiceSection}}\label{Annotations}
...
\fucnameref{Annotations}
```